# Why are my stacked vertices not merging by distance?

Tags: vertices

Object = Simple set of stairs (i.e. bunch of rectangular prisms. No complexity)

Object Mode, <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> (zero) to flatten the object

Now I have vertices stacked and want to merge them

Edit Mode, Wireframe Mode, X-Ray On, <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge By Distance* (1mm)

RESULT = *Removed 0 vertices*

I even try box-selecting a single stack of vertices with x-ray on and *Merge By Distance* doesn't do it. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Stairs]

Comment: What was the point of the "S,Z,0", and is the image you've shown before or after that action? Suggest you share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ so that we can see what's going on.

Comment: So you scale it to 0 on Z and want to merge vertices to get a flat plane with loop cuts afterwards... does it have to be done like that for some reason or could you consider to do it differently - e.g. by making a plane and putting some loop cuts on it?

Comment: Tnx Harry.
I designed a basic house in 3D, then wanted to flatten everything to make a floorplan. I've already solved this problem by simply removing all the vertices above the bottom layer and then deleting Faces Only.
I'm just super-curious as to why the Merge By Distance didn't merge any vertices. I need to let it go and move on, but it's just an unsolved riddle I was hoping to have explained.